# How to merge two files API (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am a node.js and MySQL beginner and I just started setting up and trying out some basic code.
I find these two APIs to practice, one is the API for the CRUD database, and the other is the API for judging user login / registration.I tried to merge the APIs of these two files, and the result was a problem. I think the current problem is the configuration file (conf.js).I plan to write a function and then wrap any file and use it again, so that the configuration files may not conflict, but I don’t know how to start.

These are the two API teaching URLs I practiced
http://www.expertphp.in/article/user-login-and-registration-using-nodejs-and-mysql-with-example
https://www.footmark.info/programming-language/nodejs/nodejs-restful-webapi-mysql/

`index.js`

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var authenticateController = require("./controllers/authenticate-controller");
var registerController = require("./controllers/register-controller");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/api/register", registerController.register);
app.post("/api/authenticate", authenticateController.authenticate);
app.listen(3000);
```

`app.js`

```
var bodyparser = require("body-parser"); 
var express = require("express");

var conf = require("./conf");
var functions = require("./functions");
var user = require("./routes/user");

var app = express();

req.body
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//app.use(functions.passwdCrypto);
app.use("/user", user);

app.listen(conf.port, function() {
  console.log("app listening on port " + conf.port + "!");
});
```

`authenticate-controller.js`

```
var connection = require('./../conf');
module.exports.authenticate=function(req,res){
    var email=req.body.email;
    var password=req.body.password;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?',[email], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
          res.json({
            status:false,
            message:'there are some error with query'
            })
      }else{
        if(results.length >0){
            if(password==results[0].password){
                res.json({
                    status:true,
                    message:'successfully authenticated'
                })
            }else{
                res.json({
                  status:false,
                  message:"Email and password does not match"
                 });
            }

        }
        else{
          res.json({
              status:false,    
            message:"Email does not exits"
          });
        }
      }
    });
}
```

`register-controller.js`

```
var connection = require('../conf');
module.exports.register=function(req,res){
    var today = new Date();
    var user={
        "name":req.body.name,
        "email":req.body.email,
        "password":req.body.password,
        "created_at":today,
        "updated_at":today
    }
    connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?',user, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        res.json({
            status:false,
            message:'there are some error with query'
        })
      }else{
          res.json({
            status:true,
            data:results,
            message:'user registered sucessfully'
        })
      }
    });
}
```

`user.js(models)`

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var conf = require("../conf");

var connection = mysql.createConnection(conf.db);
var sql = "";

module.exports = {
  items: function(req, callback) {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
    return connection.query(sql, callback);
  },
  item: function(req, callback) {
    sql = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userId = ?", [req.params.id]);
    return connection.query(sql, callback);
  },
  add: function(req, callback) {
    sql = mysql.format("INSERT INTO user SET ?", req.body);
    return connection.query(sql, callback);
  },
  delete: function(req, callback) {
    sql = mysql.format("DELETE FROM user WHERE userId = ?", [req.params.id]);
    return connection.query(sql, callback);
  },
  put: function(req, callback) {

    connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      sql = mysql.format("DELETE FROM user WHERE userId = ?", [req.params.id]);

      connection.query(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (results.affectedRows) {
          req.body.id = req.params.id;
          sql = mysql.format("INSERT INTO user SET ?", req.body);

          connection.query(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
              connection.rollback(function() {
                callback(err, 400);
              });
            } else {
              connection.commit(function(err) {
                if (err) callback(err, 400);
                callback(err, 200);
              });
            }
          });
        } else {
          callback(err, 410);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  patch: function(req, callback) {
    sql = mysql.format("UPDATE user SET ? WHERE userId = ?", [req.body, req.params.id]);
    return connection.query(sql, callback);
  }
};
```

`user.js(routes)`

```
var express = require("express");
var user = require("../models/user");

var router = express.Router();

router
  .route("/")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    user.items(req, function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return console.error(err);
      }
      if (!results.length) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        return;
      }

      res.json(results);
    });
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    user.add(req, function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return console.error(err);
      }
      res.status(201).json(results.insertId);
    });
  });

router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    user.item(req, function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return console.error(err);
      }

      if (!results.length) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        return;
      }

      res.json(results);
    });
  })
  .delete(function(req, res) {
    user.delete(req, function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return console.error(err);
      }
      if (!results.affectedRows) {
        res.sendStatus(410);
        return;
      }

      res.sendStatus(204);
    });
  })
  .put(function(req, res) {
    user.put(req, function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return console.error(err);
      }

      if (results === 410) {
        res.sendStatus(410);
        return;
      }

      user.item(req, function(err, results, fields) {
        res.json(results);
      });
    });
  })
  .patch(function(req, res) {
    user.patch(req, function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return console.error(err);
      }

      if (!results.affectedRows) {
        res.sendStatus(410);
        return;
      }
      req.body.id = req.params.id;
      res.json([req.body]);
    });
  });
module.exports = router;
```

`conf.js`

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "1234",
  database: "farmbot",
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Database is connected");
  } else {
    console.log("Error while connecting with database");
  }
});
module.exports = connection;

/*If I comment out the code below, I can execute the login / register API*/
/*Without commenting out, can only perform CRUD on the database*/
module.exports = {
  db: {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "1234",
    database: "farmbot"
  },
  port: 3000
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to refactor them properly. You will need only once file to begin with. Why using it twice?

Refactor them in one file instead of listening to them on different ports. Once done, you can show the code to us so that we can fix it further if there's an issue.

Start from index.js and merge app.js with it but a bit carefully. I think doing it by yourself you will learn much from it.